# Check if values in Array within a range

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check if an array I have is within certain ranges.

I have an array:

```
var times = [79, 118, 145, 245, 688, 833, 934, 956, 1019, -339, -324, -265, 65, 81, 83, 121, 151, 154, 359]
```

and want to get the count of values falling within these ranges:

```
var ranges = ['0-10', '11-20', '21-30', '31-40', '41-50', '51-60', '61 +'];
```

Here is the code I have so far..

```
$.each(times, function (i, datum) 
{
    if (datum <= 0) 
        sum1 += 1;
    else if (datum > 10 && datum <= 20) 
        sum2 += 1;
    else if (datum > 20 && datum <= 30)
        sum3 += 1;
    else if (datum > 30 && datum <= 40)
        sum4 += 1;
    else if (datum > 40 && datum <= 50)
        sum5 += 1;
    else if (datum > 50 && datum <= 60)
        sum6 += 1;
    else if (datum > 60)
        sum7 += 1;
}
```

How would I get an object of ranges and sums. e.g. {'0-10': 2, '11-20': 19, '21-30': 45}

Comment: your range would be better described as `[[0, 10], [11, 20], [21, 30], [31, 40], [41, 50], [51, 60], [61, Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY]]`

Comment: (or `[{min: 0, max: 10, label: '0-10'}, ...]`)

Comment: And, what exactly is the question you want help with?  There is no actual question in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
var times = [79, 118, 145, 245, 688, 833, 934, 956, 1019, -339, -324, -265, 65, 81, 83, 121, 151, 154, 359];

var ranges = ['0-10', '11-20', '21-30', '31-40', '41-50', '51-60', '61 +'];

function getObj(range){
    var obj={};
    range=range.replace("+","-Infinity");
    var arr=range.split("-");
    return {sum:0,min:Number(arr[0]),max:Number(arr[1])};
}

var sums={};
for(var i=0;i<ranges.length;i++) sums[ranges[i]]=getObj(ranges[i]);
for(var i=0;i<times.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<ranges.length;j++){
        var sum=sums[ranges[j]];
        if(times[i]>=sum.min && times[i] <= sum.max){sum.sum+=1}
    }
}
console.log(sums)
```

Full fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6RRyL/1/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend outputting a collection, rather than an object because it will be easier to work with; since it's an array of objects you can filter, map, and reduce, which you can't do very comfortably on objects. For example:

```
function getStepRanges(ranges, times) {
  return ranges.map(function(range) {
    var ranges = range.split(/[-+]/)
    var min = +ranges[0]
    var max = +ranges[1] || Infinity
    return times.reduce(function(acc, x) {
      // Note that your range is not inclusive
      // you may want to do "x >= min" instead
      if (x > min && x <= max) {
        acc.range = range
        acc.values = (acc.values||[]).concat(x)
      }
      return acc
    },{})
  })
}
```

Using it on this dummy data:

```
var times = [1,2,3,4,5,10,11,12,13,14,21,23,24,25,26,31,32,33,34,35,41,42,43,44,45,51,52,53,54,55,61,62,63]
var ranges = ['0-10', '11-20', '21-30', '31-40', '41-50', '51-60', '61+']
```

It will return this collection:

```
[ { range: '0-10', values: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10 ] },
  { range: '11-20', values: [ 12, 13, 14 ] },
  { range: '21-30', values: [ 23, 24, 25, 26 ] },
  { range: '31-40', values: [ 32, 33, 34, 35 ] },
  { range: '41-50', values: [ 42, 43, 44, 45 ] },
  { range: '51-60', values: [ 52, 53, 54, 55 ] },
  { range: '61+', values: [ 62, 63 ] } ]
```

#### http://jsbin.com/fowop/1/edit

With that data then you can do what you need, for example getting the maximum values:

```
var result = getStepRanges(ranges, times)

// Easy, we have a collection!
// but careful, it mutates the original object
// you may want to use an "extend" helper to clone it first
var maxRanges = result.map(function(x) {
  x.max = Math.max.apply(0, x.values)
  return x
})

console.log(maxRanges)
/*[ { range: '0-10', values: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10 ], max: 10 },
  { range: '11-20', values: [ 12, 13, 14 ], max: 14 },
  { range: '21-30', values: [ 23, 24, 25, 26 ], max: 26 },
  { range: '31-40', values: [ 32, 33, 34, 35 ], max: 35 },
  { range: '41-50', values: [ 42, 43, 44, 45 ], max: 45 },
  { range: '51-60', values: [ 52, 53, 54, 55 ], max: 55 },
  { range: '61+', values: [ 62, 63 ], max: 63 } ]*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you rewrite your range as such:

```
rangeList = $.map(ranges, function(item) {
    values = item.split('-')
    return {min: parseInt(values[0]), max: parseInt(values[1]) || Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY, label: item}
})
```

You have a nice structure. Now you have to test each value against each range. (Technically you can stop at the first that match, so you probably can use `any` instead of `each` and return true if the range is met).

```
var sums = {}
$.each(times, function(i, datum) {
    $.each(rangeList, function(rangeIndex, range) {
        if (datum > range.min && datum <= range.max) {
            sums[range.label] = (sums[range.label] || 0) + 1
        }
    })
})
```

Of course in your case, that returns `{61 +: 16}`

Answer (score 0):

No SO answer would be complete without an [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org) answer:

```
var times = [79, 118, 145, 245, 688, 833, 934, 956, 1019, -339, -324, -265, 65, 81, 83, 121, 151, 154, 359]

var ranges = ['0-10', '11-20', '21-30', '31-40', '41-50', '51-60', '61 +'];

var counts = _(ranges).reduce(function(memo, range) {
  memo[range] = 0;
  return memo;
}, {});

counts.outOfBounds = 0;

var rangePattern    = /(\d+)\s*-\s*(\d+)/;
var moreThanPattern = /(\d+)\s*\+/;
var lessThanPattern = /-\s*(\d+)/;

_(times).forEach(function(value) {
  var range = _(ranges).find(function(testRange) {
    var match;
    switch (false) {
      case !(match = testRange.match(rangePattern)):
        return (value >= match[1] && value <= match[2]);
      case !(match = testRange.match(moreThanPattern)):
        return (value >= match[1]);
      case !(match = testRange.match(lessThanPattern)):
        return (value <= match[1]);
      default:
        return false;
    }
  });
  counts[range || 'outOfBounds']++;
});

console.log(counts);
```

See it in action at this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/sihetu/1/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
var times = [79, 118, 145, 245, 688, 833, 15, 934, 956, 1019, -339, -324, -265, 65, 81, 83, 121, 151, 154, 359];
var ranges = ['0-10', '11-20', '21-30', '31-40', '41-50', '51-60', '61 +'];
var rangeStops = [0,11,21,31,41,51,61];
var rangeCounts = [0];
//sort the times first 
times.sort(function(a,b){return a - b});
var k = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < times.length; i++){    
  if(rangeStops[k] > times[i]) continue;
  else if(rangeStops[k+1] <= times[i]&&k != rangeStops.length - 1){
    rangeCounts[++k] = 0;          
    i--;
  } else rangeCounts[k]++;
}
//output
ranges = ranges.map(function(e,i){    
  var result = {};
  result[e] = rangeCounts[i];
  return result;
});
//log it and see the result in console window
console.log(ranges);
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/bFru4/7/)

Note that I added a `15` value to the array `times`, and the result should be:

```
'0-10': 0
'11-20': 1 //the 15 value
'21-30': 0
'31-40': 0
'41-50': 0
'51-60': 0
'61+' : 16 //all the other positive values
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if it's an old question I think this deserves an updated answer as javascript has evolved a lot. This is what I would do:

```
var times = [79, 118, 145, 245, 688, 833, 934, 956, 1019, -339, -324, -265, 65, 81, 83, 121, 151, 154, 359]
var ranges = ['0-10', '11-20', '21-30', '31-40', '41-50', '51-60', '61'];
const result = {}

ranges.forEach(range=>{
 const rangeNumbers = range.split("-")
let inRangeNumbers

if(rangeNumbers.length>1){
inRangeNumbers = times.filter(t=>(t>=parseInt(rangeNumbers[0]) && t<=parseInt(rangeNumbers[1])))
}else{
 inRangeNumbers = times.filter(t=>(t>=parseInt(rangeNumbers[0]))
}
 
result[range] = {range: range, amount: inRangeNumbers.length, values: inRangeNumbers}
})

}
return result
```